# Flex applies width to content-box

Tags: css

When you set the flex ratios (eg. flex: 1) they are applied to the content box (ie. padding is not taken into account). This results in some unexpected behaviour as in this example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doYBad?editors=100

```
  #c 
  {
   background: red; width: 300px; height: 40px; 
   display: flex; align-items: stretch; box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #l {background: blue; flex:1; }
  #r {background: orange; flex:2; }

  #c > * {padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block;}
```

The container is 300px. The ratio is 2 - 1 (right - left). So the left box should be 100 px, but it's not because there is padding.

How to make the flexbox apply the width to the whole box rather than just the content-box?

Note that I cannot use the width property.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you noticed is actually not entirely unexpected.

The flex-grow property is used to determine the amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up. The key here is that the **available space** is what is left after any known spaces are reserved.

In your example you have the following known properties:

- Container width: 300px
- Padding for each item: 20px (20px * 4 = 80px total)
- Left item to take up: 1/3 of the remaining space
- Right item to take up: 2/3 of the remaining space

So the calculation is done as follows:

300px - 80px = 220px

220px is the remaining space that gets divided between the two items with the left item only getting one third of this so:

220px / 3 = 73.333333r

Thus the total width of your left item is this value PLUS the padding that was assigned to is at the beginning:

73.333333r + (20px * 2) = 113.333333r

When you remove the padding you will get a 100/200 split between the left and right boxes.

Comment: Why wouldn't `box-sizing: border-box` influence this calculation?